# ssmtp myaddress@gmail.com < file.log doesn't work. Body is blank

Tags: email, rsync, smtp, stderr, ssmtp

I'm running a simple rsync script where I log stdout and stderr to two different files, rsync_stdout.log and rsync_stderr.log.

When I'm trying to email the content of rsync_stderr.log using:

```
echo $(cat rsync_stderr.log) | ssmtp myaddress@gmail.com
```

I get a blank email body, but when I do:

```
echo $(cat rsync_stdout.log) | ssmtp myaddress@gmail.com
```

then I have my stdout log in the body of the email without problem.

Is it something to do with rsync's stderr output file?
I tried everything but I just can't get it.

I ran ssmtp as verbose:

```
[<-] 250 2.1.5 OK b48smxxx70wrb.1 - gsmtp
[->] DATA
[<-] 354  Go ahead b48smxxxxxx70wrb.1 - gsmtp
[->] Received: by XXXNAS (sSMTP sendmail emulation); Tue, 19 Dec 2017 01:14:47 +0100
[->] From:"XXXNAS" <XXXNAS>>
[->] Date: Tue, 19 Dec 2017 01:14:47 +0100
[->] rsync: delete_file: unlink(.AppleDB/log.0000000001) failed: Permission denied (13)
[->] rsync: delete_file: unlink(.AppleDB/lock) failed: Permission denied (13)
[->] rsync: delete_file: unlink(.AppleDB/db_errlog) failed: Permission denied (13)
[->] rsync: delete_file: unlink(.AppleDB/cnid2.db) failed: Permission denied (13)
[->] rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1178) 
[->] [sender=3.1.2]
[->] 
[->] .
[<-] 250 2.0.0 OK 1513642487 b48sxxxxxxrb.1 - gsmtp
[->] QUIT
[<-] 221 2.0.0 closing connection b4xxxxxwrb.1 - gsmtp
```

So I can see the text being sent, but the email's body just comes blank.

I also tried ssmtp myaddress@gmail.com < rsync_stderr.log but it doesn't work either.

Comment: Did you check if is it because the stderr.log is empty?

Comment: Yes, it is not. If I just do:

    echo $(cat rsync_stderr.log), 
the log file is displaying just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After user almendrico put me on the path, I used:

`sed 's/[\:]//g'` to remove the `:` character.

Not very elegant but works.

Answer (score 1):

Well, what's the difference between both logs? You just show one of them.

I believe the ':' char present on that log is seen as a control char at SMTP's server side. You need to add '\n' before the mail body

Comment: `rsync: delete_file: unlink(.AppleDB/log.0000000001) failed: 
Permission denied (13)
rsync: delete_file: unlink(.AppleDB/lock) failed: Permission denied (13)
rsync: delete_file: unlink(.AppleDB/db_errlog) failed: Permission denied (13)
rsync: delete_file: unlink(.AppleDB/cnid2.db) failed: Permission denied (13)
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code $
sender=3.1.2`

Comment: Thanks for your answer and sorry for the late response..I had lost hope in finding a solution..I just posted the err.log. I tried to add \n at the beginning but it didn't work. The email is still blank.

Comment: Thanks Almendrico for putting me on the path..I stripped the `:` character with sed and I can get the err.log.

Comment: @brunobhr, you are welcome